# Code doesn't run in eclipse but does in command window

Tags: java, eclipse, process, runtime

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1_Exec {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p = run.exec("java Test1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream("d:\\ppp\\Test1.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("invoked successfully");
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I run the Test1_Exec in the Eclipse, Test1.txt is not created and no error is reported. But if I type "java Test1" in the command window, Test1.txt is created.  Test1_Exec.java and Test1.java are in the same src folder; Test1_Exec.class and Test1.class are in the same bin folder. So what's wrong with the Eclipse? My version of Eclipse is Kepler(20130614-0229).

Comment: It might happens so that java is confused by your JAVA_HOME  env variable if it contains whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `bin` folder in your `classpath`

```
Process p = run.exec("java -cp path/to/bin Test1");
```

Currently, `java` is looking for `Test1.class` inside your project directory.

Comment: But I think if I add bin folder(including Test1.class) in Eclipse by right clikcing ProjectName->Run As->Run Configuration | classpath Tab --- User Entries --- Advanced --- Add Folders, the statement "Process p = run.exec("java Test1")" would be OK, but it does not work. So why?

Comment: @user2158697 Because Eclipse configuration only affects the JVM environment used to run your program. It isn't automatically inherited by the JVM that you instantiate with `exec("java ...")`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to give the full path for Test1 in the command?
i.e: "java c:\code\Test1" ?